# Spring Boot + Keycloak using private certificate

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, oauth-2.0, openid, keycloak

My Spring Boot App was working fine with KeyCloak using a public certificate. But since my Keycloak has changed to a private certificate I get the following error:

```
"An I/O error occurred while reading from the JWK Set source: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
```

I've already got the private certificate but haven't figure out a successful way to set this up; If I make a curl to the Keycloack endpoint passing the certificate as parameter works fine.

```
curl --cacert mycertificate.crt -X GET \                                                                                                                                      130 ↵
https://keycloak.address.bla/auth/realms/my-app/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

I've tried to tweak my ResourceServerConfiguration class to use the certificate by generating a keystore.jks using keytool from my private certificate but I had no success; When I try the code bellow I get following error: "Cannot load keys from store: class path resource [keystore.jks]"

```
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter createJwtAccessTokenConverter() {
    var jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

    KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("/keystore.jks"), "changeit".toCharArray());
    jwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("myAlias"));
    jwtAccessTokenConverter.setAccessTokenConverter(keycloakAccessTokenConverter);
    return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
  }
```

My application.properties

```
security.oauth2.resource.id=account
security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri=${app.keycloak.api}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was solved by just importing the private certificate to my JVM. After importing the ".crt" file all my request were successful;

The command to import .crt file to JVM is as follow: `keytool -importcert -file my_certificate.crt -noprompt -alias certificate_alias -storepass changeit -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`

Comment: What is usually the default storepass in this command?

Comment: The default storepass is `changeit`, as written in the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you try setting the classloader?

```
KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks",this.getClass().getClassLoader()), "changeit".toCharArray());
```

Or you can use @Resource

```
@Value("classpath:keystore.jks")
Resource keystore;
```

...

```
 KeyStoreKeyFactory key = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(this.keystore, passphrase);
```

Comment: Yeah, I did. It loads the keystore correctly but when executes ```jwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("myAlias"));``` I get an exception with the following error: "Cannot load keys from store: class path resource [keystore.jks]"

Comment: That could be because your keystore.jks is not present in the classpath. Usually it must be saved in `target/classes` folder to be included in the classpath.